# Disable ssh-copy-id / prevent user from adding keys / add public key with web ui

Tags: ssh

I'm looking for an option to hinder users to add their public key with ssh-copy-id. So that an admin has to upload it (like github and other services) with a webui.

For example: I tried to add my keys to a cloudways instance but can not log in with them, Instead I have to use their web ui. I want to achieve the same. Also I'm looking for the web ui part. If you have any pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In sshd_config, change `AuthorizedKeysFile` to something users cannot write to.

Implement your desired way of looking up keys with `AuthorizedKeysFile` or `AuthorizedKeysCommand`.  Many possible ways to get such keys, regular files, user directory lookups, get from a web server, DNS TXT records.  Pick one that fits your environment.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. That sounds great. I will do some research on that. Especially getting a key from DNS TXT records grabbed my attention. Even though I'd like to use a web server.